# Trouble with QSerialPort with qtcreator on Debian

Tags: linux, git, qt, github, debian

I'm currently trying to use the "QSerialPort" library on a Virtual Machine with Debian on it and can't seem to make it work. It looks like the Library straight up doesn't exist on my machine. It doesn't auto-complete when I write it out and when I try compiling I get this.

```
/home/debian/Downloads/mainmenu.h:15: error: QSerialPort: No such file or directory
 #include <QSerialPort>
                       ^
```

So I'm pretty sure I just don't have the library. Even though my version of Qt is said to have it.

-Qt Creator 4.2.0 
-Based on Qt 5.7.1 (GCC 6.3.0 20170415, 64 bit)

I even have an older version of Qt creator on my Windows OS and it has the library.

I was told to get the library myself by doing this:

```
git clone git://code.qt.io/qt/qtserialport.git
mkdir qtserialport-build
cd qtserialport-build
qmake ../qtserialport/qtserialport.pro
sudo make install
```

but I can't even get through the first line before getting this:

```
git clone git://code.qt.io/qt/qtserialport.git
Cloning into 'qtserialport'...
fatal: unable to connect to code.qt.io:
```

Also tried to install the Package: libqt5serialport5 (5.2.1-1)

and it pretty much changed nothing.

Comment: Try `git ls-remote git://code.qt.io/qt/qtserialport.git`, it works for me. If it doesn't work for you — it's network problems. Perhaps you're behind a proxy. Try different protocols: `http://code.qt.io/qt/qtserialport.git`, `https://…`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to download and install. Just follow my instructions given below, it will help you to fix the problem.

You are very close man (Also tried to install the Package: libqt5serialport5 (5.2.1-1))

1) You have to install (via Terminal):

```
sudo apt-get install libqt5serialport5
sudo apt-get install libqt5serialport5-dev
```

2) add in the .pro file

```
QT  += core serialport
```

3) int the .h file add:

```
#include <QtSerialPort/QSerialPort>
#include <QtSerialPort/QSerialPortInfo>
```

4) Example Device Info

```
 serial -> setPortName("/dev/ttyACM3"); // just example for my device
 serial -> setBaudRate(QSerialPort::Baud115200);
 serial -> setDataBits(QSerialPort::Data8);
 serial -> setParity(QSerialPort::NoParity);
 serial -> setStopBits(QSerialPort::OneStop);
 serial -> setFlowControl(QSerialPort::NoFlowControl);
 serial -> open(QIODevice::ReadWrite);
```

It is probably the best option.

Answer (score 0):

Alright! I figured it out.

First problem, was accessing a git library through a Firewall/Virtual Machine.

So instead of using the git link:

```
git://code.qt.io/qt-creator/qt-creator.git
```

I used the http link, which worked:

```
http://code.qt.io/qt-creator/qt-creator.git
```

Still had some issues until I followed these steps(I didn't download the dev version of the package, I guess):

```
1)
sudo apt-get install libqt5serialport5
sudo apt-get install libqt5serialport5-dev

2) add in the .pro file
QT += serialport

3) int the .h file add:
#include <QtSerialPort/QSerialPort>
```

Comment: It's network problem, https://packages.ubuntu.com/zesty/libqt5serialport5